# How to open google map link in iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

i have a google map url how can i open this in iframe
url: `http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=14735+32A+AVE+Surrey+V4P+1Z8+bc&spn=0.012065,0.040770&iwloc=A&hl=en`

and i am using this iframe to open/embed the map in iframe

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=14735+32A+AVE+Surrey+V4P+1Z8+bc&amp;spn=0.012065,0.040770&amp;iwloc=A&amp;hl=en" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Its not showing me anything. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the [link](http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=14735+32A+AVE+Surrey+V4P+1Z8+bc&spn=0.012065,0.040770&iwloc=A&hl=en) in a web browser.
2. click on the "gear" in the lower right corner (on the "new" Google Maps).

[image: Gear]

3. Choose "Share or embed map"
4. Click on the "Embed Map" tab
5. Choose a size
6. Copy the provided iframe code use it on your page.  It will look like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d21056742.211671695!2d-97.15369!3d49.891235!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1s14735+32A+AVE+Surrey+V4P+1Z8+bc!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1424618801986" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```